# StimulusJS with Turbolinks, have to wait for "turbolinks:load" event to execute StimulusJS controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, stimulusjs

I have a fairly standard Rails 5.2 app (follows pretty much all conventions) using yarn and webpacker, with stimulus version `1.1.1` in my `package.json` and `yarn.lock` file.

```
# package.json
{
  "name": "MY_APP_NAME",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.2",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

From the StimulusJS Discourse page (https://discourse.stimulusjs.org/t/stimulusjs-and-turbolinks/669), starting with Stimulus `1.1`, stimulus controllers execute connect/initialize methods after DOM is ready with turbolinks.

However, the only way I could get the below controller to execute properly is to add the event handler to wait until the `turbolinks:load` event fired.

If it's relevant info, I'm trying to use the jQuery Select2 plugin to create a custom select element.

```
# app/javascript/packs/controllers/intake_customization_controller.js
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "userIds" ]

  initialize() {
    // Code will not execute without this event handler wrapping it...
    $(document).on("turbolinks:load", ()=> {
      $(this.userIdsTarget).select2()
    })
  }
}
```

The HTML form:

```
<%= form_with model: @account, url: settings_intake_customization_path, method: :put, id: "settings-intake_customization-form", data: { controller: "intake-customization" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.collection_select :user_ids, current_account.users, :id, :name, { include_blank: false }, { multiple: true, data: { target: "intake-customization.userIds" } } %>
<% end %>
```

Am I missing something with setting up the stimulus controller with turbolinks?

Using the `turbolinks:load` event handler, I can get the functionality I want, but from what I read on the Discourse forum, I shouldn't have to use the event handler.

Is it possible that my app has "cached" an older version of Stimulus, even though the `package.json` says otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, Stimulus has been designed to work in conjunction with Turbolinks. I would be surprised if you needed to wrap your code inside of the event handler for `turbolinks:load`. It is possible that you may be looking to use the `connect` event rather than the `initialize` event because the `initialize` event is fired off when the controller is first instantiated. The `connect` event is fired off anytime the controller is connected to the DOM.

From the [docs](https://stimulusjs.org/reference/lifecycle-callbacks#connection) for the `connection` lifecycle callback, it states:

> A controller is connected to the document when both of the following conditions are true:
>
> - its element is present in the document (i.e., a descendant of document.documentElement, the  element)
> - its identifier is present in the element’s data-controller attribute
>
> When a controller becomes connected, Stimulus calls its connect() method.

Since you want to manipulate the DOM with jQuery Select2, the `connect` lifecycle callback seems more appropriate to me. I will do some more research, but I would imagine that the `initialize` event is fired whenever the code for the controller is loaded in the browser. If that is the case, then there is a possibility the `initialize` event is getting fired before the part of the DOM tree that uses your controller (and the DOM element you're trying to query) has had a chance to render:

```
# app/javascript/packs/controllers/intake_customization_controller.js

import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "userIds" ]

  connect() {
    $(this.userIdsTarget).select2()
  }
}
```

I was able to find an [article](https://johnbeatty.co/2019/03/13/convert-your-jquery-snippet-to-a-stimulus-controller/) says to use `connect` rather than `turbolinks:load`. This article is written by someone who has published a handful of [Stimulus tutorials](https://johnbeatty.co/stimulus-js-tutorials/) so he seems fairly reputable. I'm having trouble finding anything that goes into detail about the differences between `initialize` and `connect` other than that `initialize` is fired once and `connect` is fired every time it's attached to the DOM. In order for `connect` event to be fired again, there needs to a `disconnected` event fired in between

Comment: Had the same problem but with `$(this.userIdsTarget).selectpicker()`. Using `connect()` is the way to go.